# Pandas: combine data frames of different sizes

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 data frames:

df1 has ID and count of white products

```
product_id, count_white
12345,4
23456,7
34567,1
```

df2 has IDs and counts of all products

```
product_id,total_count
0009878,14
7862345,20
12345,10
456346,40
23456,30
0987352,10
34567,90
```

df2 has more products than df1. I need to search df2 for products that are in df1 and add total_count column to df1:

```
product_id,count_white,total_count
12345,4,10
23456,7,30
34567,1,90
```

I could do a left merge, but I would end up with a huge file. Is there any way to add specific rows from df2 to df1 using merge?

Comment: Unclear why you think a left merge would produce a huge file, by performing a left merge on the product id you are stating that you are only interested in matches in the product_id column only

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just perform a left [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) on 'product_id' column:

```
In [12]:

df.merge(df1, on='product_id', how='left')
Out[12]:
   product_id  count_white  total_count
0       12345            4           10
1       23456            7           30
2       34567            1           90
```

Comment: I completely messed up the data frames and was merging on the wrong one. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

#### Perform left join/merge:

Data frames are:

[image]

left join:

```
df1=df1.merge(df2, on='product_id', how='left')
```

The output will look like this:

[image]